# Combine two tables and search float +-10

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in a SQLite database - schools and persons.

```
Table: schools
+----------+-----+-----+
|   name   |  X  |  Y  |
+----------+-----+-----+
| School 1 | 100 |  40 |
| School 2 |  23 |   2 |
| School 3 |  98 | -50 |
+----------+-----+-----+
```

...and...

```
Table: persons
+----------+----------+----------+
|  person  | person_X | person_Y |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Person 1 |       95 |       42 |
| Person 2 |       24 |        4 |
| Person 3 |       98 |      -10 |
| Person 4 |      160 |      111 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to list all persons where person_X and person_Y matches the X and Y in the school table +-10. So in this case I would like the result to be: Person 1 and Person 2 (because they are close to School 1 and School 2).

I have tried many ways, but get it only to work. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just requires a join with criteria which checks the range overlap:

```
SELECT
    p.person,
    s.name
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN schools s
    ON p.person_X BETWEEN s.X - 10 AND s.X + 10 AND
       p.person_Y BETWEEN s.Y - 10 AND s.Y + 10;
```

[image]

### Demo